# Passing Event Method to Grandchild Component

Tags: reactjs

I'm a bit new to React, so forgive me if this is a bit of a newb question.

I have a base component (Page) which uses state to control whether or not a modal popup is displayed:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        showModal : false,
        modalContent : 'Initial Modal Content'
    };

    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
}

showModal(modalContent) {
    this.setState({
        showModal : true,
        modalContent : modalContent
    });
}

hideModal(e) {
    this.setState({showModal : false});
}
```

My problem is that I want a grandchild component to be able to open up my modal.

I know I can do this by passing the state to the child component and then to the grandchild component:
    `<PartnersTable showModal={this.showModal} partners={PARTNERS} />`

That just seems a bit sloppy to me, but maybe that's just the React way.

Can someone let me know if I'm doing this properly or if there's a cleaner way to do this?

You can view my full app on GitHub: https://github.com/CCChapel/Thy-Kingdom-Come/blob/master/react.js

Thanks!

-Eric

Comment: Passing down a function that alters the `showModal` is probably the most Reacty way to do it. You might want to look into pulling out the state from the component with e.g. [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) or [MobX](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) if it gets messy.

Comment: Redux/Flux are what you want. Are you 100% sure inheritance is best solution for this? Composition is usually better than inheritance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing it correctly.

In React the only way for a parent to pass props/state to it's children is by passing it downwards. React is unidirectional from top to bottom; from parent to child only.

So your assumption is correct. It can get pretty sloppy. You must know that React is for presenting the UI and simple cases of state management. When you're application gets more complex and you need to pass down state in a direct and simplified manner use Redux, MobX or any other state containers out there.

If you don't like the complexity of passing down props down the tree considering using Redux (I use Redux myself).

Consider the following resources:

- https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux
- http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/
- https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples

To learn how React works though get used to using only React first then use a state container when the application gets more complex.

Comment: Thanks, Keith! At least I know I'm doing it right. I'm using this one page, microsite as a means to test out React and expand my knowledge of it, so I'll take your.advice and not get into Redux just yet. This honestly is the most complex part of the app. Thanks again!

Comment: @EricRovtar you're welcome. If this answer suffices I'd appreciate it if you'd accept it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you need to pass your **showModal** method as a prop to child component(s) in which you want to trigger the visibility of the modal. This is how the render method of the parent component should be:

```
render() {
    return(
        <ChildComponent showModal={this.showModal}>
    )
}
```

Then in you child component:

```
class ChildComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <input type="button" onClick={this.props.showModal} value="show modal"/>
        )
    }
}
```